# What is the difference between denied to you and denied you

Tags: meaning, word-difference

I am reading a text and the text say.

"has love been denied you?"

I tried to work it out but it makes no sense to me

Should the text say

Has love been denied to you?

Thanks for the explanation in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

One pattern is

**deny**  {someone} {something}

> They denied him water.

Another pattern is

**deny** {something} **to** {someone}

> We cannot give her a  salary but deny one to the other intern.

The practical meaning of these patterns is the same.

> We cannot give her a salary but deny the other intern one.